# Using SVNKit, how can I switch a directory to a different branch?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I have a working directory in `trunk` and would like to switch it to a specified branch. How can I do that?

I'd like to have a method

```
public static void switchToBranch(File baseDir, String branchUrl){
}
```

How could I implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Update]** Better version:

```
public static void switchToBranch(final String branchUrl,
    final File basedir,
    final ISVNDebugLog log) throws SVNException, IOException{
    final SVNUpdateClient updateClient =
        SVNClientManager
            .newInstance().getUpdateClient();
    if(log != null) updateClient.setDebugLog(log);
    updateClient.doSwitch(basedir,
        SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(branchUrl),
        SVNRevision.HEAD,
        SVNRevision.HEAD,
        SVNDepth.INFINITY,
        false,
        false);
}
```

Credentials are apparently automatically picked up from the ~/.subversion directory.

(And of course it doesn't have to be a branch, SVN doesn't make a difference between tags, branches or any other path)